# How to convert a number based on milimeter to a number that says which part is meter , centimeter and milimeter?

Tags: python, type-conversion, typeconverter

My code tries to convert a number to for example **X** meter **Y** centimeter and **Z** milimeter.My code works correctly for numbers with out any zero like **5782** but when it comes to numbers with zero it will not work properly

This is my code :

```py
a = 2200
b = a / 1000
print(float(b))
b = str(float(b)).split(".") 
first = b[0] 
print(first,b[1])

c = (float(b[1])/10)
print(c)
c = str(c).split(".")
print(c)

second = (c[0])
third = (c[1])



print("%s Meter %s centimeter %s milimeter"%(first,second,third))
```

The result has to be like **2 meter 20 centimeter 0 milimeter** but it gives me **2 meter 0 centimeter 2 milimeter**

How can i solve that guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use integer division:

```
print( 27 // 4 ) # prints 6 because 6*4 = 24 and 7*4 is too big
```

With integer division you get how many "full" meters are in 2200*mm* (2) and then you substract 2*1000 from the `mm` value, continue with `cm` and whats left over are `mm`.

```
mm = 2200        # startvalue in mm

m = mm // 1000   # how many full meters in mm?
mm -= m*1000     # reduce mm by amount of mm in full meters

cm = mm // 10    # how many full centimeter in mm?
mm -= cm*10      # reduce mm by amount of mm in full centimeters

print(f"{m} meter {cm} centimeter {mm} millimeter")
```

Ouput:

```
 2 meters 20 centimeter 0 millimeter
```

If you want to omit a zero value you would need conditional printing:

```
if m != 0:
    print(f"{m} meter ", end="")
if cm != 0:
    print(f"{cm} centimeter ", end="")
if mm != 0:
    print(f"{mm} millimeter", end="")
print() # for the newline
```

Comment: @mega yours is fine as well, this is just ... simpler

Answer (score 2):

You really, really, *really* shouldn't use `int` to `str` conversion and the `split` method to remove decimals...

So, what I see you are doing is millimeters to meters, centimeters, and millimeters. What I would do is use `math.floor` to remove the decimal places -

```
import math
a = 2200
meters = math.floor(a / 1000)
centimeters = math.floor((a - meters * 1000) / 10)
millimeters = math.floor(a - meters * 1000 - centimeters * 10)
print(meters, centimeters, millimeters)
```